# JndiObjectFacotryBean method is ignoring @DependsOn with latest spring version

Tags: spring, spring-boot

with springboot 2.2.4 version JndiObjectFactoryBean gets called after JndiTemplate bean is created , but after upgarding version to 2.4.5 JndiObjectFacotryBean method is ignoring @DependsOn and its bean creating before JndiTemplate.

```
@Bean("jndiTemplate")
    public JndiTemplate getJndiTemplate() {
        jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(initialContextName,
                initialContextValue);
        properties.setProperty(providerUrlName(),
                providerUrlValue());
        jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(properties);

        return jndiTemplate;
    }

    @Bean("jndiObjectFactoryBean")
    @DependsOn({ "jndiTemplate" })
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean getJndiObjectFactoryBean () {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean   jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate); //NULL with springboot 2.4.5 and not null with 2.2.4 version
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to spring-boot 2.4.5 release notes:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.4.5

you have upgraded Spring Framework to 5.3.6 version.

Try to use:

```
@Bean(name= "jndiObjectFactoryBean")
@DependsOn(value= { "jndiTemplate" })
```

You might also try to force the use of spring framework in spring boot 2.2.4 setting the following property in your pom, but I cannot say if you might have dependency problems in your application. At least you need a deep non regression test.

```
<properties>
  <!-- Other dependencies -->
  <spring-framework.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
  <!-- Other dependencies -->
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.  I have tried it. still JndiObjectFacotryBean is getting created before JndiTemplate Bean. Can you suggest anything else?